# NGX-bootstrap Datepicker fires TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setHours')

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

Struggling with the problem in DatePicker component.
Here is the simple test project: https://github.com/yardim/datepicker-test

Steps to reproduce:

1. Enter some invalid value into DatePicker input with a keyboard, for example text: `asd`
2. Remove focus from the input, input automatically will be filled with value: `Invalid date`
3. Put focus into input again, and wait until datepicker appears
4. Select `Invalid date` text and remove it from the input

**Actual result**: it fires error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setHours')
at copyTime (ngx-bootstrap-datepicker.js:2249)
at bsDatepickerReducer (ngx-bootstrap-datepicker.js:2310)
at ngx-bootstrap-mini-ngrx.js:12
at scanInternals.js:11
at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:9)
at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31)
at observeOn.js:6
at QueueAction.<anonymous> (executeSchedule.js:3)
at QueueAction._execute (AsyncAction.js:53)
at QueueAction.execute (QueueAction.js:20)
```

Does anybody know any workaround how to fix that issue and prevent error?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like this is a bug in ~7.1.2 version. Can confirm 6.2.0 and 8.0.0-RC.5 work without error.